# Очень простая ошибка в php коде

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку в коде:

```
file_put_contents($file, '<center><b>'.$name.'<br>'.$dom.'<br>'.$vid.'/'.$text.'
  </center></b><br>
  <center><i>Текст Домашнего задания</i></center><br>'.$komm.'<br>'.file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: @Женька, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А что за ошибка-то?

Comment: Вы файл и на чтение и на запись получается открываете, зачем?

Comment: В коде нет ошибок.

Comment: Попробуйте сначала прочитать содержимое в переменную, а потом сформировать файл и записать. А то я не знаю, в каком порядке интерпретатор PHP вычисляет аргументы.

Кроме того, у вас там по всем полям XSS на XSS'е, вы бы экранировали значения переменных что ли.

Comment: @VladD, так можно делать - разницы никакой нет, **ошибкой** ТС называет то, что программа ведет себя не так, как он хотел вероятнее всего.

Comment: @Женька 

>где ошибка?

Это нам бы было интересно. И где ошибка? покажите ошибку, которая возникает, а тут подскажут как ее решить.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Угу. На моей памяти у какого-то неопытного юзера словосочетание "программа не работает" означало "кнопка не на том месте, где я ожидаю её найти". Пичалько.

Comment: @Женька, Что именно у Вас задано в переменной ***$file***?  
В данном случае, там должно быть лишь название и путь к вашему файлу. Типа:  

    $file = "file.txt";

Comment: Итак, спасибо всем, что отозвались)
У меня есть и это $file = "file.txt";
но вот какую ошибку выбивает:
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: @Женька, невозможно. Такую ошибку выдает только если пустая строка передана как имя файла.  
Проверьте $file на содержимое.  
Возможно, у Вас нечто вроде:  

    $fiIe= "test.txt"; 
Тут не буква **l** , a **I** («И» большая вместо «л» маленькой)

Comment: да нет вроде)
Все нормально, но все равно что-то не работает..

Comment: @ReinRaus правильно сказал, такого быть не может. Вам PHP ясно сказал "Имя файла не может быть пустым" значит $file у вас пустой. перед тем кодом, что вы нам дали, сделайте 

    var_dump($file);

и посмотрите чему равна эта переменная

Comment: хм, странно, спасибо..

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ни о чём.

Answer (score 4):

Это нас тестируют в честь НГ, что ли? Окай )
Синтаксических ошибок пэхапэ вроде нет.
Но если придираться...

- файл $file может и не существовать, будет предупреждение. самый простой вариант - "@" перед file get contents
- запись в файл не транзационная, могут быть конфликты. хорошо бы перейти на fopen со всякими lock'ами. или вообще fopen с "at", если не принципиально, с какой стороны файла новые данные добавлять
- как отметил [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), тут таки нет экранирования данных. по названию переменных предположу, что все переменные кроме $dom содержат plain text. и надеяться, что этот $dom - не от клиента идет ))
- ошибка хатэмэле: center закрыли раньше, чем b
- ошибка русского языка: "домашего" не надо с большой буквы писать (а что? придираться так по полной!)

Если что - не воспринимайте мой ответ всерьез, новый год же =)

Comment: ахах, всем большое спасибо)
исправил все что можно - заработало)
ещё раз спасибо:)
С наступающим, кстати)